# iOS Google Analytics. How to track only app launches?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I want to get information about app installs and new/active users. Nothing else. No events, purchases, etc. Maybe uncaught exceptions. I use Google Analytics v3.14 (pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.14') and this code to setup tracking:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"my-trackerID"];
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
gai.dispatchInterval = 120;
gai.defaultTracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;
```

However, when I look into google analytics report I see only few users (it must be much more). If I try to force sending analytics with `[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];` I see

```
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:368): No pending hits.
```

in logs. Is it possible to track only app installs and new/active users? If so then how?

Comment: Don't have to do anything, the above statements will automatically track app installs and new users for you.

Comment: @satheeshwaran unfortunately, it doesn't. In fact, I see only 2 users in analytics reports. I can't see tracked app install or user activity even when trying to launch app on device right from Xcode. What am I doing wrong? It seems like GA SDK doesn't want to send analytics without at least one event. But I have no events.

Comment: Fyodor any solution?

Comment: @gyer it is really old question. As I remember, there were no solution to this besides adding at least one action to track. Maybe situation have changed since then and analytics frameworks now support mentioned behavior, but I didn't check for it.

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok thank you for your respond.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142?hl=en

Did you try this??

Comment: Kindly up vote the answer or accept it if it helped you.